# Does double slit in a vacuum have any effect?

Tags: particle-physics, double-slit-experiment

If you do the double slit experiment in a foggy or smokey room, it seems like your going to smudge out the interference pattern, right?

Continuing in the other direction it seems intuitive that a vacuum would lead to a crisper interference pattern than a space filled with air.

Is it experimentally known if the interference pattern is crisper in a vacuum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fog or smoke interact with light in two main ways:  absorption and scattering.  Absorption will reduce the intensity of the interference pattern.  Scattering can take light that was going to somewhere bright and send it to somewhere dim, so will wash out the pattern as you are thinking.  Clear air doesn't scatter light (much), so your pattern should be (almost) as sharp as in a vacuum.

Comment: Is that to say the vacuum will in fact be a little crisper?

Comment: Yes, but probably by an amount hard to notice.